# How to rectify this run time error 1004 "Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed"?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a workbook which has 10 sheets. I am trying to export these sheets into different workbooks and name them based on their previous sheet names. I am using the below code and when I am running it, some of the sheets get exported to the specified folder and then this run time error pops up.

Weird thing is, each time I execute the code, the number of sheets that get exported before the error popping up is different. So for example, when I first execute the code, 2 sheets get exported and error comes. Another time if I execute 1 sheet exports and error comes. Another time 4 sheets get exported and error comes.

I am not able to find out how to rectify this error.

Please help me.

```
Sub ex()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbToSave As Workbook
Dim filePathToSave As String


   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("KA V DUMP.xlsb").Activate

filePathToSave = "C:\Users\SHRAVAN.BOLLINENI\OneDrive - U\Desktop\F st\"

For Each ws In Workbooks("KA V DUMP.xlsb").Worksheets
 
      ws.Copy
      Set wbToSave = ActiveWorkbook

      'MsgBox filePathToSave & ws.Name & ".xlsx"

      wbToSave.SaveAs _
      Filename:=filePathToSave & ws.Name & ".xlsx", _
      FileFormat:=51

      wbToSave.Close True

 Next ws

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe the name of the sheet contains characters that are not allowed in a file name?

Comment: If you are using Windows, further to @FunThomas's comment, characters allowed in sheet names but not allowed in file names (suggest you remove any of these from your sheet names if that is possible ... if not, can share code to remove them during the save process) are the following after this colon: | " < >

Comment: Also (again if you are using Windows) the following filenames (with or without the .xlsx extension) are not allowed: "com1" to "com9", "lpt1" to "lpt9", "con", "nul", "prn" and "aux" ... so if your sheet names clash with those, you may see errors

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a sleep may help, module:
Sleep 200 means 200 ms. Give Excel Time to close the workbook.

```
Option Explicit
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub ex()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wbToSave As Workbook
Dim filePathToSave As String


   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks("KA V DUMP.xlsb").Activate

filePathToSave = "C:\Users\SHRAVAN.BOLLINENI\OneDrive - U\Desktop\F st\"

For Each ws In Workbooks("KA V DUMP.xlsb").Worksheets
 
      ws.Copy
      Set wbToSave = ActiveWorkbook

      'MsgBox filePathToSave & ws.Name & ".xlsx"

      wbToSave.SaveAs _
      Filename:=filePathToSave & ws.Name & ".xlsx", _
      FileFormat:=51
      Sleep 200 ' ##############################################
      wbToSave.Close True

 Next ws

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope. VBA is single threaded. There is no point in adding a sleep